# powershell will eventually close my remote opened application

Tags: powershell, remote-server, powershell-remoting

I have this script in powershell:

```
$session = New-PSSession -ComputerName WIN-1.domain.net         


Invoke-Command -Session $session -ScriptBlock {  
 
    cd "D:\serviceJar"
    Start-Process -PassThru -FilePath java -ArgumentList ('-Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Xms64m -Xmx256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=512m -jar javapp.jar -Dfile.encoding=utf-8')
}


Disconnect-PSSession -Session $session  -IdleTimeoutSec 2147483647 -OutputBufferingMode Drop
```

which basically opens a remote session and starts a java application.

everything is ok, however as you can see in disconnect session, IdleTimeoutSec max value is 2147483647  (around 24 days) and this is going to end my user's session and all processes created with it.

I can't find a way to set it to infinite, is there another way to do it?

I also tried to connect using a local administrator account, but I cant get a successful connection, so I used my local domain account to do connect

tried this but is not a valid int32:

```
Set-Item -path WSMan:\localhost\Shell\IdleTimeout -Value '999999999999999999'
```

this just set a default value (2 hours):

```
 Set-Item -path WSMan:\localhost\Shell\IdleTimeout -Value ''
```

Comment: What happens if there is a power cut or the server is taken down for maintenance?

Comment: well this actually is an application that runs automatically, I just didn't want to include all script, but before that, the process is killed, updated jar and run again

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to wrap powershell star-process in a Invoke-CimMethod:
as the documentation mention it:
[Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1#notes)

example of the solution:

```
$arguments = @{                
       CommandLine = 'powershell Start-Process java -ArgumentList ('' -Xms64m -Xmx192m  -jar  myApp.jar'')'
    }
    Invoke-CimMethod -ClassName Win32_Process -MethodName Create -Arguments $arguments
```

***Note that using java -jar myApp.jar directly in Invoke-CimMethod  also  kills the application***